# Running Firefox 8 and Firefox 5 simultaneously

Tags: firefox

I am trying to run Firefox 8 and Firefox 5 versions at the same time on my Windows 7 machine.

Firefox 8 is my default browser and I installed Firefox 5 using custom options in a separate folder. I created a new profile for Firefox 5.

I am able to load both versions individually using

```
"C:\...\Mozilla Firefox 8\firefox.exe" -p default
```

and

```
"C:\...\Mozilla Firefox 5\firefox.exe" -p "Firefox 5"
```

commands.

However, I am not able to load them simultaneously. I even tried the -no-remote option. When I use the -no-remote option, it is trying to load the no-remote website.

Comment: Something is screaming out from my head, "Why the **** would you want to do that?" :)

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to load the no-remote website"?

Comment: @Mehrdad: New versions can bring new bugs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ah, I see. Although, to be honest, I have seen *little difference* from version 4 to version 5, and observed *no* difference from then up to version 10. I have no idea what the heck they're doing... is there any difference between versions 5 and 10, to make me want to use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps are for the `FF2` and `FF3` so I think they will work with the `FF8` and `FF5` as well.
For more information you can go on the Source link I've provide bottom of the answer.

First, you should create a new profile just for testing Firefox 3. You should do this to keep your precious Firefox profile safe from any problems in Firefox 3. Otherwise, Firefox 3 will use your current Firefox 2 profile by default. You can create a new profile easily with the Profile Manager, which you can access by running:

```
/path/to/firefox -profilemanager -no-remote
```

If you get confused, the official Firefox website has more detailed instructions on [how to create a new profile](http://www.mozilla.org/support/firefox/profile)
You can start up Firefox 2 normally (just so you can see Firefox 2 and 3 running side by side).

We’re gonna run Firefox 3 using our newly created profile.

```
/path/to/firefox3 -P minefield -no-remote &
```

Firefox 3 should start up with your new clean profile!

[Source](http://blog.codefront.net/2007/08/20/how-to-have-firefox-3-and-firefox-2-running-at-the-same-time/)

Comment: Firefox 8 with no parameters, and Firefox 5 with '-P "Firefox 5" -no-remote' did the trick for me.

Comment: Really happy that its worth for you.